# Web socket connection was successful with 101 protocol change but facing error while getting message from server

Tags: spring, ionic-framework, spring-websocket

Using spring web socket server side for constant updates from the server to client (ionic application is the client), using STOMP for connectivity.

Facing issue after getting connected. `"Unhandled frame: stomp.js:134 <<< c[1007,"null"]"` at client side and `"com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'CONNECT': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')"` error is observed at server.

Console log at client side :

Opening Web Socket...
 Web Socket Opened...

> > > CONNECT
> > >       accept-version:1.1,1.0
> > >       heart-beat:10000,10000

<<< o
 Unhandled frame:

<<< c[1007,"null"]
 Unhandled frame: 
content-length:13

[1007,"null"]
 Whoops! Lost connection to ws://127.0.0.1:8080/...

Comment: Your server should return `CONNECTED` frame, but return something like `c[1007,"null"]"`

Comment: Can you please let me know how to clear the issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue (c[1007,"null"] and parse exception) with okhttp3. Did you ever figure out what was the problem?

Comment: Yes, It got connected now. I was facing to connect to websocket from flutter now. Can you share the exception which you got @DavidSAlderson

Answer (score 0):

If you use SockJS with Stomp on Java Spring, you must encapsulate your Stomp frame with socket JS protocol.

for send `"CONNECT\naccept-version:1.1,1.0\nheart-beat:10000,10000\n\n" + String.fromCharCode(0)`

you must send this frame: `"[\"CONNECT\\naccept-version:1.1,1.0\\nheart-beat:10000,10000\\n\\n\\u0000\"]"`

dart code:

```
String data = "CONNECT\naccept-version:1.1,1.0\nheart-beat:10000,10000\n\n" + String.fromCharCode(0);
data = "[${json.encode(data)}]";
```

Or if you don't use Sock JS

try change (char)0 inside stomp frame by \u0000